# tikz arrow tip thickness for double lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a double line with an arrow in both ends, but when I try to do it the thickness of the arrow tip becomes too big.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm] (a) {A};
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm, left = 3cm of a] (b) {B};
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm, left = 3cm of b] (c) {C};

  \draw[angle 90-angle 90, line width=1pt, double, double distance=5pt] (a.west) -- (b.east);
  \draw[angle 90-angle 90, line width=1pt] (b.west) -- (c.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: to clarify, what I want is to decrease the arrow tip thickness for the double line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Classical TikZ Rightarrow[]}]
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm] (a) {A};
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm, left = 3cm of a] (b) {B};
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm, left = 3cm of b] (c) {C};

  \draw[<->, line width=1pt, double, double distance=5pt] (a.west) -- (b.east);
  \draw[<->, line width=1pt] (b.west) -- (c.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Classical TikZ Rightarrow]

**Little Improvement**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Straight Barb[round]}]
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm] (a) {A};
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm, left = 3cm of a] (b) {B};
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size = 2cm, left = 3cm of b] (c) {C};

  \draw[{<._[sep=-13pt]}-{_[sep=-13pt].>}, line width=1pt, double, double distance=5pt] (a.west) -- (b.east);
  \draw[<->,line width=1pt] (b.west) -- (c.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thankk you for the answer